# Expanding / Exploding column values with Nulls into multiple rows in Pyspark

Tags: pyspark, inline, explode

I have the following data as per below:

[image]

I would like to expand this data to get the following data:

[image]

I have tried the following code:

```
df = (df
  .selectExpr("id", 
              "split(col1, ',') col1", 
              "split(col2, ',') col2",
              "split(col3, ',') col3")
  .withColumn("arr", F.expr("arrays_zip(col1, col2, col3)"))
  .selectExpr("id", "inline(arr)"))
  df.show()
```

This code result in 0 rows.
So I have tried to use the command 'inline_outer':

```
    df = (df
  .selectExpr("id", 
              "split(col1, ',') col1", 
              "split(col2, ',') col2",
              "split(col3, ',') col3")
  .withColumn("arr", F.expr("arrays_zip(col1, col2, col3)"))
  .selectExpr("id", "inline_outer(arr)"))
  df.show()
```

This code brings back all the rows but without any value.

I am at this stage puzzled as to why this happens as if I expose the original column (e.g. col1 without splitting, etc.) the values are there.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using `arrays_zip` with `null` value returns `null`. For your case, we need empty array instead of null.

```
cnd = "arrays_zip(coalesce(col1,array()),coalesce(col2,array()),coalesce(col3,array()))"

df = df.selectExpr("id","split(col1, ',') col1","split(col2, ',') col2","split(col3, ',') col3").\
withColumn("arr", F.expr(cnd)).selectExpr("id", "inline_outer(arr)")

df.show()

+---+----+----+----+
|id |0   |1   |2   |
+---+----+----+----+
|x  |1   |a   |c   |
|x  |2   |b   |c   |
|x  |3   |c   |c   |
|y  |null|null|null|
|z  |12  |null|c   |
|z  |3   |null|null|
+---+----+----+----+
```